# Need second line of output from a wmic get last modified command entered into a variable without writing to a file

Tags: wmic

(need help obviously).

I have this working:

```
wmic datafile where name="%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%" get lastmodified > tmpFile.txt
set /p myvar-a= < tmpFile.txt
type tmpFile.txt | findstr /v LastModified > tmpFile2.txt
set /p myvar-b= < tmpFile2.txt
del tmpFile.txt
del tmpFile2.txt
```

`tmpFile.txt` has this:

```
LastModified               
20150429124836.260625-240
```

`tmpFile2.txt` has this:

```
20150429124836.260625-240
```

`echo %myvar%`   *produces this:* `20150429124836.260625-240`

How can I get the `wmic` command to just get "`20150429124836.260625-240`" without writing to a file every time?
Somehow use "`skip 1`" ?

(the whole thing is in a loop - lots of unnecessary file writing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi this works:      
wmic datafile where name="%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%" get lastmodified /format:list

Comment: it produces this:   produces this:    LastModified=20150429124836.260625-240

Comment: However, assuming this:  %sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%      actually echos to be this     D:\\DEVEL\\somefile.txt

Comment: the following does not work:     for /f %%a in ('wmic datafile where "name='%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%'" get lastmodified ^| find "=" ') do set "val=%%a"
echo again here [%val%]

Comment: the error is this:  error is   -Invalid alias verb

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in comments as it worsens readability; [edit] your question rather.

Comment: If any answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code snippet (`name` changed to a constant value for better readability, should work with `where "name='%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%'"` clause as well).

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (
  'wmic datafile where "Name='d:\\temp\\virus.bat'" get LastModified/value'
) do for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%G") do set "myvar=%%x"
```

Where the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `LastModified` value;
- `%%x` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`), see the example below.

**Example** (copy & paste from my command line window):

```
==>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %G in ('wmic datafile where "Name='d:\\temp\\virus
.bat'" get LastModified/value') do @echo "%G"
"20150512194153.372487+120

==>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %G in ('wmic datafile where "Name='d:\\temp\\virus
.bat'" get LastModified/value') do @for /F "tokens=*" %x in ("%G") do @echo "%x"
"20150512194153.372487+120"

==>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

This works:

**for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic datafile where "name='D:\DEVEL\somefile.txt'" get lastmodified /format:csv') DO SET myvar=%%A**

also this works (don't need the skip=2) also substituted variable for path and name:

**for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic datafile where "name='%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%' " get lastmodified /format:csv') DO SET myvar=%%A**

**ECHO your modified variable is here: %myvar%**

My entire problem may have just been the quotes - pay close attention to the single and double quotes below - its critical! This version is also delimiting with a comma, but it may work with "=" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz)

I was able to get this to work:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic datafile where "Name='%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%'" get LastModified/value') do @echo %%G
```

- Output:

```
20150512153513.391860-240
```

Also, this:

(although I am not sure how any of them differ with respect to result)

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic datafile where "Name='%sourcepathdoubleslashnoquotes%%FileName%'" get LastModified/value') do @for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%G") do @echo %%x
```

- Output:

```
20150512153513.391860-240
```

- **`ECHO`** your modified variable is here: **`%myvar%`**